# Does the block declared inside a @synchronized section get synchronized?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, synchronized

While implementing lazy thread-safe getter I encountered an interesting (in my opinion) situation where I had to use `@synchronized` section with block declared and invoking inside this section. Here is the simplified version of the code:

```
- (void) someMethod
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        [self doSomethingWithCompletionBlock:^{
            // Are we synchronized here?
        }];
    }
}
```

Are we synchronized (by self) inside the block? If so, does the block capture (in terms of memory management) the self pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block itself will not be synchronized.

However, if you are executing this block synchronously on the same thread, then it will still run inside of the existing synchronized block.

If OTOH you pass the block along to another thread, it will not synchronized anymore.